# How to create document in Couch base with "no replication"?

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api, xdcr

Hi Couch base Experts,

We have got two clusters with replication on, we want to identify which cluster, our java application is writing to. So we are thinking of adding an unique document to each cluster, we can then query the document to find out name of the cluster. But issue is, with replication on, both documents would become available in both clusters and our logic to identify cluster based on existence of a document will fail. Has anyone faced similar issue before? can we turn off replication for a particular set of documents?

Answer (score 0):

You could set cluster name in settings on admin UI:

[image: setting cluster name]

And then you could query it via REST call

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8091/pools/default?waitChange=1 | jq .clusterName
"foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure/filter  what can be replicated between clusters (XDCR). This can be achieved using regular expressions, so as long as you have a pattern / uniqueness, you can either make it replicate or stop it from replicating. 
Go to XDCR tab and create replication, check Advanced Replication option --> Filter expression ( you can also test of a match is found ). 
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujx7R.png)